# append folder to curPageURL

Tags: php

I am using php to grab and echo curPageURL

```
<?php echo curPageURL(); ?>
```

that gives me something like: http://mywebsite.com/folder/

Which is great, but I also want to add another href , to redirect to:
http://mywebsite.com/folder/thankyou/

But I would like to append /thankyou/ to curPageURL

so like: curPageURL/thankyou/

does that make sense ?

It is for use on fb feed api, and wish to add a redirect_uri using my code ( I have everything working ) just not the /thankyou/ bit …

Was just wondering if I can append a directory onto the end of the CurPageURL

( I don’t really want to use explicit url )

Ste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed ( just wasnt thinking )

```
$thisurl = curPageURL();
$thanks = "thanks/";
$thaturl = $thisurl . $thanks;
```